# How do latch transforms work?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting this error after publishing latch transforms for camera-link to base-link.
The code is at the end of the errors...

```
[ERROR] [1380316527.758532146, 2.527000000]: Error getting latest time from frame 'camera_link' to frame 'base_link': Could not find a connection between 'base_link' and 'NO_PARENT' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees. (Error code: 2)
[ERROR] [1380316527.758625055, 2.527000000]: Error getting latest time from frame 'hokuyo_frame' to frame 'base_link': Could not find a connection between 'base_link' and 'NO_PARENT' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees. (Error code: 2)
[ERROR] [1380316527.767405664, 2.528000000]: Error getting latest time from frame 'camera_frame' to frame 'base_link': Could not find a connection between 'base_link' and 'NO_PARENT' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees. (Error code: 2)
[ERROR] [1380316527.767563302, 2.528000000]: Error getting latest time from frame 'camera_link' to frame 'base_link': Could not find a connection between 'base_link' and 'NO_PARENT' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees. (Error code: 2)
[ERROR] [1380316527.767687690, 2.528000000]: Error getting latest time from frame 'hokuyo_frame' to frame 'base_link': Could not find a connection between 'base_link' and 'NO_PARENT' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees. (Error code: 2)
```

My code is as follows:

```
  tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster static_broadcaster;
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped msg;

  msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  msg.transform.rotation.x =  0.0;
  msg.transform.rotation.y =  0.0;
  msg.transform.rotation.z =  0.0;
  msg.transform.rotation.w =  1.0;

  msg.header.frame_id = "base_link";   
  msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.z = 0.1;
  msg.child_frame_id = "camera_link";
  static_broadcaster.sendTransform(msg);

  msg.header.frame_id = "camera_link";   
  msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.z = 0.2;
  msg.child_frame_id = "hokuyo_frame";
  static_broadcaster.sendTransform(msg);

  msg.header.frame_id = "camera_link";   
  msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
  msg.transform.translation.z = 0.3;
  msg.child_frame_id = "camera_frame";
  static_broadcaster.sendTransform(msg);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84411/how-do-latch-transforms-work?/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-09-27**:
Did you try broadcasting these frames from a launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In part this was caused by not bring up the node doing the latches before the rqt_gui which was bringing up rviz as default. Apparently this makes a difference. Now I am left with one error which I will place under a different question.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0